# Get included module name in module's method

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

Is it possible to get the name of module being included in its class method?

Some code that satisfy the following example:

```
module Helper
  def module_name
    # return module name for which method is being called
  end

  def new_module
    name = module_name
    define_method :initialize_module do
      extend foo? ? Object.const_get("New#{name}") : Object.const_get("Old#{name}")
    end
  end
end

module A
  extend Helper
  new_module

  module NewA
    def some_method
      'Successfully extended NewA'
    end
  end

  module OldA
    def some_method
      'Successfully extended OldA'
    end
  end
end

class B
  include A

  def initialize
    initialize_module
  end 

  def foo?
    true
  end
end

class C
  include A

  def initialize
    initialize_module
  end 

  def foo?
    false
  end
end

B.new.some_method
#=> 'Successfully extended NewA'

C.new.some_method
#=> 'Successfully extended OldA'
```

Comment: what about when you have multiple modules included?

Comment: You're right, I have updated example to be more specific.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've never had to dynamically define `module` extension methods before, it's unusually difficult to manage on a `class` but you can always manage this using an intermediate module to help package and import the methods wherever you want:

```
module Helper
  def self.extended(base)
    base_name = base.to_s

    extension = Module.new

    extension.send(:define_method, :module_name) do
      base_name
    end

    base.send(:extend, extension)
  end
end

module A
  extend Helper
end

module B
  extend Helper
end

A.module_name
# => "A"

B.module_name
# => "B"
```

This is probably a lot less messy than defining module instance variables. Closures, in practice, tend to be a lot cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

```
module A
  def module_name
    A.class_name
  end
end

class B
  include A
end

B.new.module_name  # => 'A'
```

Comment: The example I provided was not specific enough - I have updated it. Please, take a look.